# Jquery-ui and js-autocomplete conflict on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I have a wordpress site where I use jquery-ui and js-autocomplete.
I am not sure how to use noconflict with wp_register_script function.
I register the scripts using

```
    // jquery-1.10.2.min.js
    //wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js', array(), '1.10.2', false );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js', array(), '1.10.2', true );

    // jquery-ui.js
    //wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/js/libs/jquery-ui.js', array(), '1.10.3', false );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js', array(), '1.10.3', true);


    // owl carousel
    wp_register_script( 'owl-carousel', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/js/libs/owl.carousel.min.js', array(), '1.3.2', true );

// autocomplete class
    wp_register_script( 'js-autocomplete', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/js/libs/jquery.autocomplete.min.js', array(), '1.1', true );
```

On One page I fetch data from my wordpress using wp-admin/adim-ajax.php

Problem is jquery-ui.js and autocomplete are comflicting and only one feature works.

How do I resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should download the latest JQuery-ui framework **including** the autocomplete widget, and remove the call to the autocomplete script alone.

Hope it helps